Overlay multiple ImageSources automatically in WinUI / WPF using Itemsrepeater/ItemsControl
I have created several Bitmaps with a transparent background to display data. The data loads correctly, but I'm having trouble overlaying these images. I need help adjusting the layout of an ItemsRepeater or ItemsControl so that it stacks images on top of each other without a predefined layout.
My goal is to recreate the following structure using ItemsRepeater or a similar control:
<Grid>
    <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Source="{x:Bind ViewModel.ImagePath1, Mode=OneWay}" 
           AutomationProperties.Name="cliff" Stretch="Uniform"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Source="{x:Bind ViewModel.ImagePath2, Mode=OneWay}" 
           AutomationProperties.Name="cliff" Stretch="Uniform"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
<!-- Images from 1-n -->
</Grid>



But I can't get the images to overlay properly. How can I achieve this layout using ItemsRepeater or another suitable control?
I tried using ItemsRepeater like this:
<ItemsRepeater ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.ContourPlots, Mode=OneWay}" 
               ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ContourPlotImageTemplate}" />
<Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Source="{x:Bind ViewModel.ImagePath2, Mode=OneWay}" 
       AutomationProperties.Name="cliff" Stretch="Uniform"
       HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>


This worked for me:
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.ContourPlots, Mode=OneWay}">
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Grid />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="ContourPlotImageTemplate" />
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ContourPlotImageTemplate" x:DataType="viewmodels:ContourlineUIHolder">
        <Image Visibility="{x:Bind CVisibility, Mode=TwoWay}" Source="{x:Bind ContourlineSource, Mode=TwoWay}" AutomationProperties.Name="cliff"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
